# Differences passing Redux state through passProps with Navigator or binding state within Container

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, navigator, react-redux

Testing **React Native** with **Redux**, and **react-redux**, I've found that the content of the state tree of Redux is not reflected in the display if the state is not passed through a Container.

To test this i use

- react-native 0.19.0
- react-redux 4.1.2
- redux 3.1.7

as @alinzin explain in https://github.com/alinz/example-react-native-redux with all the tricks to setup this project. Are out there any other good solution?

The next example show a simple string as state in Redux store, and a simple action for enlarge the string.

Here is the reduce and the data as a single string in the state.

```
//Reducer
const reducer = (state = { data: '[][][]' }, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case ENLARGE:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      data: state.data+'[]'
    })
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

The registred App is like this, nothing new. The initial route launches a Container for App1Component. This is the way for good binding state and Components (I belive)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigator style={{flex: 1}}

          initialRoute={{
            component: Container,

          }}

          renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
            const Component = route.component;
            return (
              <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop:40}}>
                <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} {...route.passProps} />
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

The main content for both component App1Component and App2Componenet, is a simple component and just display the string, and show a 'button' to dispatch the enlarge action.

```
class MainContent extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.data}-{this.props.data.length}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.enlarge()}} >
          <Text>Click to Enlarge me!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text> </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

There are no differences between components App1 and App2.
Just App1Component is invoked through a Container (and bind state and actions), and App2Component invoked (from App1Component) by pushing with Navigator all the same props (the same in App1Component)

Here is App1Component with a button to push next scene to App2Component and pass the same props, before binded through Container.

```
class App1Component extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <MainContent {...this.props}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'App2',
            component: App2Component,
            passProps: {...this.props}
           })
        }}>
          <Text>Click to Forward to App2Component {'\n'}passing props through Navigator passProps</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

If you press 'enlarge' here the string is enlarged, and you can see the action reflected on the screen. Also you can see in chrome the trace for redux logger.

Here the wrapper container for App1Component

```
const Container = connect(
  (state) => ({
    data: state.data
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    enlarge: () => dispatch(enlarge())
  })
)(App1Component)
```

And Here Component 2, with back button.
If you press 'enlarge' here the string is enlarged, sure you can see the trace on chrome, but ... the action is not reflected on the screen.

```
class App2Component extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MainContent {...this.props}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.navigator.pop()}} >
            <Text>Back to App1Component{'\n'}to see the change!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

After pressing Back, you can see the string modified on screen for App1Component.

As you can see I misunderstood something fundamental, but not what is.

Have i to decorate all the mains components (Pages/Scenes) with a container? 
Why is wrong to pass props (previously binded by container) through passPros in Navigator? Actions are dispatched correctly, but does not reflect on the screen.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`passProps` does not propagate updates correctly](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/795). I’m not a React Native expert so I can’t confirm it, but I would definitely recommend you to use `connect()` for subscribing components to Redux store rather than passing props from the top.

Comment: @gaearon

Thanks Dan.  I really apreciatte your answer.

I have resume my questions on this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535456/need-help-on-some-concepts-about-reactnative-and-redux-and-navigator)

Can you comment on it?